# Converting datetime formats in a series with default values for when the respective variables are not included in the origin

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm importing data from a csv file. One of the columns on my df is a column with datetime info, but its data is somehow dynamic. Sometimes it includes time info, sometimes not; sometime it informs the timezone, sometimes not.

The data starts as a `2516 non-null object`

The following is an example of a series with only the date - no time nor timezone:

```
         datetime
0       2020-08-15
1       2020-08-14
2       2020-08-13
3       2020-08-12
```

I'm converting to datetime using `pd.to_datetime` and `dt.strftime`to change the data format. So for the code below...

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d-%Z-%H-%M-%S')
```

... and the sample data, I end up with the following output:

```
0       20-08-15--00:00:00
1       20-08-14--00:00:00
2       20-08-13--00:00:00
3       20-08-12--00:00:00
```

Note there are two `--` together because there's no timezone in the origin and `%Z` returns nothing; and time values end up as `00:00:00` because they are not provided either.

What I would like to achieve is to add a default value to the timezone when those are not provided by the origin, so that becomes explicit; and add default time values to populate entries where these are not provided by the origin either.

Is it possible to do something like we do with default values for function arguments?

```
def funct(arg1, arg2=x, arg3="xyz")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use localisation you need to state your locale.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,8,12), dt.datetime(2020,8,15))})
df["datestr"] = df["date"].dt.tz_localize("Europe/London").dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d-%Z-%H-%M-%S')
```

**output**

```
      date                datestr
2020-08-12  20-08-12-BST-00-00-00
2020-08-13  20-08-13-BST-00-00-00
2020-08-14  20-08-14-BST-00-00-00
2020-08-15  20-08-15-BST-00-00-00
```

Answer (score 1):

My go to for this sort of thing is [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). So for your case:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil import tz 

dt = parse('1970-01-01 12:00+0')
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())

parse('2020-08-15', default=dt)                                                                                                                                           
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 15, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())

print(parse('2020-08-15', default=dt))                                                                                                                                    
2020-08-15 12:00:00+00:00
```

The `dt` is created as a template for the parsing. Anything not provided by the input datetime string is replaced with the template values. In this case the time and the timezone. You could this as a replacement in the apply function.